# disable keypad after entering text in textfield

Tags: iphone

I am new to iphone;

what i did is creating a 10 labels with corresponding text fields.

when i click on text field keypad is open.

But it covers the bottom 4 textfields.

I can't able to enter text to those fields.

i need when i click textfield  in front of keypad screen moves up.

now i can able to enter in those  textfields.

How can i done this.

Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jumhyn wrote, make the UIViewController the delegate of all the text fields. Then assign the text fields tags from 0 to 9, from top to bottom. Then implement the following method in the controller:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    self.view.bounds = CGRectOffset(self.view.bounds, 0, textField.tag * 50);
    [[self.view viewWithTag: textField.tag + 1] becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

The idea is that the first line shifts all the text fields up, depending on which text field has been edited, in the second line you activate the next text field. You will have to modify the code to better fit your layout, but it should give you the idea.

Comment: Thank q for replay, i try this but no change to my view.

Comment: Check out this article to better understand the machinery: http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/sliding-uitextfields-around-to-avoid.html

Comment: i think u r code is correct i place NSlogs in function that are in above link. But that functions are not fired. what i need to do to fire those events

Answer (score 0):

Make the UIViewController that handles the text views a UITextFieldDelegate:

```
@interface TextFieldViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {
```

then in the textFieldShouldBeginEditing: method in the .m file, add the code that moves the text fields up. For example:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
     myTextField3.frame = CGRectMake(myTextField3.frame.origin.x, myTextField3.frame.origin.y - /*whatever you want to subtract from the y value*/, myTextField3.frame.size.width, myTextField3.frame.size.height);

     myTextField4.frame = CGRectMake(myTextField4.frame.origin.x, myTextField4.frame.origin.y - /*whatever you want to subtract from the y value*/, myTextField4.frame.size.width, myTextField4.frame.size.height);

     myTextField5.frame = CGRectMake(myTextField5.frame.origin.x, myTextField5.frame.origin.y - /*whatever you want to subtract from the y value*/, myTextField5.frame.size.width, myTextField5.frame.size.height);

     myTextField6.frame = CGRectMake(myTextField6.frame.origin.x, myTextField6.frame.origin.y - /*whatever you want to subtract from the y value*/, myTextField6.frame.size.width, myTextField6.frame.size.height);

     return YES;
}
```

Comment: How do the text fields get the message if they are obscured by the keyboard? Also, the method must return YES.

Comment: When the view loads, no keyboard will be present and therefore any text field could be tapped. This would move all the textfields that he said are covered (the bottom four) up by whatever amount he wants. Also just wondering, what is the advantage to using CGRectOffset as opposed to reassigning the frame?